# read IEnumerable text list and issue move commands C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to read a list in text file and move the files source to target directory. But as I am trying to read this file using for statement it's giving me following error :

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   `System.IO.StreamReader` because `System.IO.StreamReader` does not
>   contain a public definition for `GetEnumerator`

Not sure if this is issue with file creation or some alternate approach is needed here to read and then move files.

Please advise.

Here's the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    create_source_fileList();
    string source_dir = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SourceDir"];

    string target_dir = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TargetDir"];

    string dpath = target_dir + "Diff" + ".txt";

    TextWriter df = new StreamWriter(dpath);

    DirectoryInfo sourceinfo = new DirectoryInfo(source_dir);

    DirectoryInfo targetinfo = new DirectoryInfo(target_dir);

    string[] source_f_list  = File.ReadAllLines(target_dir + "Source_File_List.txt");
    string[] target_f_list = File.ReadAllLines(target_dir + "Target_File_List.txt");

    IEnumerable<String> file_list_diff = source_f_list.Except(target_f_list);

    string diff_list = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, file_list_diff);


    df.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, file_list_diff));
    df.Close();


    System.IO.StreamReader file_read = new System.IO.StreamReader(target_dir + "\\Diff.txt");


    if (!Directory.Exists(targetinfo.FullName))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(targetinfo.FullName);
    }



    /*foreach (FileInfo fi in sourceinfo.GetFiles())

    {

            fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(targetinfo.ToString(), fi.Name), true);
    }*/



    foreach (string file in file_read)  // Error With For Loop
    {


    }

    create_target_fileList();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can't use `foreach` directly with `StreamReader`. It doesn't have the required members for `foreach` to work.

Options:

- Use `File.ReadLines` instead:

  ```
  string path = Path.Combine(targetDir, "Diff.txt");
  foreach (string file in File.ReadLines(path))
  {
      // ...
  }
  ```
- Repeatedly call `ReadLine` on your `StreamReader`, which should be in a `using` statement and is simply obtained using `File.OpenText`:

  ```
  string path = Path.Combine(targetDir, "Diff.txt");
  using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(path))
  {
      string file;
      while ((file = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
          // ...
      }
  }
  ```

Note that I've made the variable names a bit cleaner too - idiomatic variable names in C# are things like `sourceFileList` rather than `source_f_list`.

Additionally, I'd encourage you to use `File.WriteAllText` earlier on, rather than the way you're using `df` (without a `using` statement, and opening it much earlier than you need to).